# while...else Statement for Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Is there a possibility to add an else after a while-Loop in Arduino, like there is in Java or C#? Something like this:

```
while(condition){
  doThingA;
} else{
  doThingB;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

C# does not have `while...else` and I don't think Java has this construct either. Python has it and because the instructions in the `else` block are not executed only when you break from the loop you can emulate it as follows:

```
bool flag = TRUE;
while (condition)
{
    if (anothercondition)
    {
       flag = FALSE;
       break;
    }
}

if (flag)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No maybe, it's not actually because it is based on embedded c, which includes syntaxes similar to c. So to conclude it simply can't. was a pleasure to help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
ESPserial.print(params + '\n');

time = millis();
while(true) {
    int avail = ESPserial.available();

    if (avail) break;
    if (millis() - time > 500) break;
}

do {
    char ch = ESPserial.read();
    data += ch;
} while (ESPserial.available());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't have a else after a whole loop but u can put a exclamation(!) before the statement like:

`while (!condition)`
or`while(value1 != value2)`